# Create array from string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a **string** like that :

```
$str = "array (
   'from' => 'OK',
   'to' => 'OK',
   array (
      'id' => 204847
   ),
)"
```

How could I create the array that matches ?
Or how could I get the id ?

Comment: how did you get such a string in the first place?

Comment: This is going to take you into unwanted territory. Can you change the input to be in a recognised interchange format such as JSON or XML?

Comment: If you store the data yourself make sure you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php after that you can use unserialize

Comment: look at eval  e.g. eval('$myarray='.$str.';');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this string is not user input the easiest way would be to use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

```
eval('$myArray = '.$str.';');
```

**Important note** from the documentation:

> The `eval()` language construct is ***very dangerous*** because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. ***Its use thus is discouraged***. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention ***not to pass any user provided data*** into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: add a semi-colon on the end too

Comment: **This post requires a big frakoff warning attached to it.**

Comment: Please note the use of single quotes, so its a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use PHP's `eval()` function thought you need to be CERTAIN that this string is trusted.. even then I am loathe to recommend it:

**Documentation:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

**Warnings:** [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) for why it is evil

Comment: Hmm, just discovered that "loathe" rather than "loathed" is correct, here, moments before editing your post. Thanks!

Comment: It will make me loathed, but I loathe myself :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to break the "answer the question as posed" mould because `eval` is extremely dangerous and I shall not even come close to recommending its use.

Instead, change your string to a recognised interchange format, such as [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) or even [XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php). Or [PHP's native serialisation format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)...